# Chrome slow on request against 127.0.0.1 via "fake" domain (domain.local)

Tags: google-chrome, webserver, localhost

I'm having troubles on my local dev environment with Chrome since an unknown moment in the past, some request (I would say about 90% of them) are really slow, it takes about 10 secs to start transfering data.

[image: This is what my Network inspector looks like.]

I'm running Mac OS X (Lion, but it's been happening before) and MAMP as local web server. It also happens with Apache2+PHP5 installed through MacPorts.

It only happens on Chrome, the web server works as expected on Safari and Firefox. My about:version says this:

Google Chrome   12.0.742.122 (Official Build 91910)

I tried enabling DNS Pre-fetching but the option is gone, I'm not sure since when while it updates by itself.

My /etc/hosts looks like this:

```
#DEV
127.0.0.1       website1.local
127.0.0.1       website2.local
```

Comment: - did you try with chromium? - are you using chrome extensions that might trigger this?

Comment: @Adirael, does it happen with other file-types like JPG, etc. or only with PHP files? Try navigating directly to some non-PHP files on your server to check.

Comment: Happens too pointing to a JPG with all extensions disabled, same behavior as with PHP files: sometimes fast as lighting, but most of them slow as a turtle.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

thee matter is Lion handles .local TLD differently because it's reserved for some Multicast DNS features (used by Bonjour). The only way i found to solve this issue is using a different TLD for development hosts (ie: .dev). It works fine for me

Comment: Seems to be working, I changed to .dev and now they're fast. Weird thing is on Firefox they worked OK, maybe Firefox caches the DNS requests and Chrome is not doing it anymore.

Comment: This worked for me on Win7 as well, so it might not be limited to just Lion.